# Filter data (data.frame) according an attribute and assign it to a vector

Tags: r, loops, filtering

Good afternoon,

I have a large data frame (+20000 rows) with three columns, two columns are the x-y coordinates of a point and the third one indicates an important attribute of that point (+100 different attributes in total).
I would like to filter the data for each attribute, so basically classify the points according to each attribute. The part of the problem that makes it difficult for me is the +100 attributes, as it then needs to be done in a loop (e.g for loop)

```
#data looks like this:

x y att
1 1 a
2 3 a
4 6 a
3 5 b
5 5 b
4 1 c
etc.
```

Notice that each attribute doesn't have the same amount of points...

Thank you very much,
any suggestion would help

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you'd like to split your data frame into separate data frames, one for each attribute? That can be done with:

```r
require(dplyr)

data %>%
group_by(att)
group_split(att)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` like below

`split(df,df$att)`

Comment: I knew it was way more easier than I thought, thanks a lot